Run Windows PowerShell commands from PowerShell (`powershell.exe` vs `pwsh.exe`)

Run pwsh.exe (i.e. C:\program files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe)
Try running a Windows PowerShell specific command such as below
PowerShell (pwsh) does not understand it!

> Get-WmiObject -query "SELECT Version From Win32_OperatingSystem"

Get-WmiObject: The term 'Get-WmiObject' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

The only way is to launch Windows PowerShell (powershell.exe) and then execute it.
Alternatives (from pwsh):
> powershell Get-WmiObject -query "SELECT Version From Win32_OperatingSystem"

That fails.  So, add single quotes around:
> powershell 'Get-WmiObject -query "SELECT Version From Win32_OperatingSystem"'

Well, the how do I run this then (note the 10.0%)?
Get-WmiObject -query "SELECT Version From Win32_OperatingSystem 
   where Version like '10.0%'"


Get-WmiObject has been deprecated long ago and removed in pwsh. Use Get-CimInstance instead which is much faster and also cross-platform

Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54495023/995714

@phuclv I see the problem exists only on Windows 10, and not on Windows 11 or 2025! All three have same version of PowerShell (7.4.5), but on newer OS, Get-WmiObject works fine!

powershell and pwsh will start different versions.
Check the output of $PSVersionTable.
Get-WmiObject ist deprecated in PowerShell 3.0 and above. The cmdlet is superceded by Get-CimInstance.

I see the output of $PSVersionTable to be same for both. And both list multiple versions under PSCompatibleVersions

I think you are right... Just that I didn't update PowerShell to latest on one of my VMs.
